# LocalSocket communication with Unix Domain in Android NDK

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming, android-ndk, unix-socket

I have Android application, which needs to establish unix domain socket connection with 
our C++ library (using Android NDK)

```
public static String SOCKET_ADDRESS = "your.local.socket.address"; // STRING
```

There is LocalSocket in java which accepts "string" (your.local.socket.address)

```
#define ADDRESS     "/tmp/unix.str" /* ABSOLUTE PATH */
  struct sockaddr_un saun, fsaun;
    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("server: socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    saun.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(saun.sun_path, ADDRESS);
```

But the unix domain socket which is at native layer accepts "absolute path". So how can these two parties communicate to each other?

Please share any example if possible

Comment: note that on android the temp shared folder is at `/data/local/tmp`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

LocalSocket uses the Linux abstract namespace instead of the filesystem. In C these addresses are specified by prepending '\0' to the path.

```
const char name[] = "\0your.local.socket.address";
struct sockaddr_un addr;
addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

// size-1 because abstract socket names are *not* null terminated
memcpy(addr.sun_path, name, sizeof(name) - 1);
```

Also note that you should not pass `sizeof(sockaddr_un)` to  `bind` or `sendto` because all bytes following the '\0' character are interpreted as the abstract socket name. Calculate and pass the real size instead:

```
int res = sendto(sock, &data, sizeof(data), 0,
                 (struct sockaddr const *) &addr,
                 sizeof(addr.sun_family) + sizeof(name) - 1);
```

Comment: This helped me a lot! However I have an issue with getting the client's sockaddr and and length on the server side. I want the client to send a msg to the server (through UDP) and then the server should respond to the client with information. I use recvfrom(_serverSocket, _messageBuffer, INPUT_BUFFER, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&_clientAddress, &_clientAddressLength); on the server side, however _clientAddressLength is zero, and the _clientAddress is empty, and I cannot respond to the client, despite the fact that the msg from client to server was received correctly.

Comment: This is my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755790/sockets-unix-domain-udp-c-recvfrom-fail-to-populate-the-source-address?noredirect=1#comment51445587_31755790

Answer (score 0):

[Pro Android C++ with the NDK book, chapter 10](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=LImysDUJDBUC&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260&dq=localsocketactivity.java&source=bl&ots=CAiQWdhdrO&sig=alyXWhYt3_EwN2pWgWpy_iwz_Zo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=W5MLUZzPEuuPiAeJw4DgAQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA) helped me to get started with the same.