# AF_UNIX socket server write to itself in C

Tags: c, sockets

Can a socket server created with **socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)** write to itself?

I'm asking this becouse the first send is ignored if it was from the same server to the same server, but if it a client is the one who sent it then it not ignored.

why does that happen and how to not ignore the first send from server?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29346883/1216776

Comment: How would you connect the server to itself?