# Unix Socket Implementation sending sockaddr info

Tags: c++, sockets, unix-socket

I would like to know if it is possible to create unix domain socket, with **Socket_Stream** configuration where server and client binds their own sockets so that they could be able to send their sockaddr information.

In other words I would like to send sockaddr from one side to another. With that I would like to control and distinguish multiple clients on the server side.

1. However as I understand you cannot receive **sockaddr** information in connection-mode. In other words you cannot use accept-connect while sending Unix socket sun_path information as **sockaddr**. Is it right conclusion?
2. As you can see in question below, It is possible to send sockaddr by binding both sockets and using **sendto recv** function. But Is it possible to use it also with connect-accept mod. since I could not be able to run that example with SOCK_STREAM (connect accept doesn't allow SOCK_DGRAM) configuration. Is there a way to do this

[Sockets, Unix Domain UDP C++ recvfrom fail to populate the source address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755790/sockets-unix-domain-udp-c-recvfrom-fail-to-populate-the-source-address)

Comment: To send information between unrelated processes (even processes running the same program) you need some kind of channel to transmit that information. Like a `AF_LOCAL` socket (or a pipe, or other [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) method). If you don't already have such a channel, then you can't transmit information. So it seems you have a kind of [catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)) situation going on: You need to create a connection, but you can't create it unless you already have a connection.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  hello yes. But if there is a way to do this with connect-accept mode I would love to listen other wise, I plan to do this: Main process will send its own path to other side-Processes in his first message, other process will knew it his MainProcess is awakened and Side Processes will also send connection request to Main process.

Comment: why not simply make a TCP socket on localhost interface, it should be as efficient as a unix socket (besides making the code more portable)

Comment: Unix domain sockets are faster way to do this I believe @YannTM

Comment: depends on your throughput whether this is significant enough to matter : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973942/tcp-loopback-connection-vs-unix-domain-socket-performance#:~:text=When%20the%20server%20and%20client,(on%20Linux%20for%20instance). If you really want efficiency on a stream communication that only work on unix Named Pipes (mkfifo) should be even better you just exchange file (named pipes) names as addresses.

Comment: Thank u man @YannTM, it is decided already.

Comment: I believe no one will answer my question anyway. Could u plz upvote so that some one can see this. Even a No answer as a fact, would be nice @YannTM

Comment: Sorry my answer is not really answering your question since it is proposing workarounds. You should put a bounty on the question to attract more answers.